# How to switch off this kind of modal windows

Tags: dynamics-crm

Where to look for code that calls a window like this? Is it JavaScript on browser's side or something else? This modal window is shown to fix an address of work order (when user changes it) and make it the same as the address of account. I do not want it and need to switch the window off.

[image]

Comment: On the 'Debugger' tab of the developer tool you can find a list of javascript files included in the page, you can try that. Otherwise in the form editor, check if there is some javascript called on change of the field.

Answer (score 1):

It is Javascript which is firing on change of your Field (work order).

It is quite easy to turn it off.

Go to Setting--> Customizations click on it

[image]

Then click on Customize the system

[image]

Then Select your Main form.

[image]

Then click on your particualr filed and popup will open something like below

[image]

When you double click you will see below option, just uncheck enable and the function which is firing on change of your work order will be disabled.

[image]